# php SQL multiple IN arrays

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to execute the following query:

> SELECT * FROM inbound WHERE direction = 'inbound' AND shortcode IN (60777) AND `trigger` IN (G6AAJ) ORDER BY daterecieved DESC LIMIT 1

But I get the error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'G6AAJ' in 'where clause'

I cannot figure out why, any with this help appreciated.

Comment: Quotes are your friend if the column is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

It's interpreting `G6AAJ` as a column name, try `IN ('G6AAJ')`